# Why are sky textures not showing up?

Tags: texturing, materials, light

I'm a Blender noob and trying to do something I thought would be simple, but is causing me grief. I'm trying to add a sky outside the windows of the classroom scene found [in this Blender file I found online](http://download.blender.org/demo/test/classroom.zip).

I've tried the tutorials [here](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/03/11/adding-clouds-to-blender-cycles-sky-texture/) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/how-to-add-a-sky-in-cycles), and neither of them show any alterations to the scene when I go through the steps. It's like something in the setup of the file is overriding what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have no idea what's going on, or how to even find what settings to tweak, turn on/off etc. Any guidance would be wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be due to a several things:

- *Transparent* is enabled in *Render settings > Film*.
  This renders the image with alpha transparency instead of sky. Useful for compositing, but hides the sky texture (at least in viewport render).
- Ray visibilities are disabled on the world material.
- The compositing setup doesn't take into account the sky texture. This is understandable, as a real-life camera would over-expose the sky when taking a picture with a reasonably exposed interior.

So to make this work, you'll need to modify the compositing setup.

---

Start by adding your sky texture to the world material. Ensure the strength is set correctly and at least *Camera* ray visibility is enabled:

[image]

Disabling *Properties > Render > Film > Transparent* won't work in this particular case, since the compositing setup uses it create glare from the sky. Instead you can use the *Environment pass*:

1. Enable the environment pass in *Properties > Renderlayers > Passes*:

   [image]
2. Connect the environment pass output of the `_mainScene` *Render layers* node to the *Alpha over* node in the `COLOR CORRECTION` frame:

   [image]
3. You may have to reduce the amount of glare by reducing the *Fac* value of this mix node:

   [image]

Render:

[image]