# sky texture is rendering in black

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I set up my background to sky texture but when rendered it shows black, here is a picture of it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your world material node setup.

Comment: Please read the rules of the site; do not add an answer when providing additional information,  [edit] your question instead. As for your question - is *Camera* option unchecked in World tab > Ray Visibility rollout ?

Comment: it was checked so i unchecked it but still same problem!

Comment: It is meant to be checked. It controls whether world texture is visible for camera (i.e. rendering) or not. Is it possible for you to [upload the blend file on this link](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: maybe related http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6800/19287

Comment: just uploaded the file sorry if its a bit large, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *Transparent* enabled in render settings > film.

[image]

Disable that and you'll see the sky...

Comment: Generally if *Transparent* is checked it should show checkerboard which means transparency, not solid black. For some reason this is caused by Background Images in the Properties shelf (the rollout is just enabled, there aren't any). Don't know if it's a bug.

Comment: @MrZak Yes, it took me a little while to find that, and it wasn't exactly what I was expecting when I saw it. It could very well be a bug...