# Where is Environmental Lighting in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, world

I took a break from Blender for a year or two, and now, after updating to 2.8, I can no longer find the *Environmental Lighting* setting that was in the *World* tab.

Has this been removed, or displaced, or has it been replaced? Where can I find it or a substitute for it?

A picture has been attached for reference as to what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: What render engine you'd like to use? Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: Perhaps this helps you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158336/using-material-preview-hdri-in-renders-blender-2-81

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a sky in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/how-to-add-a-sky-in-cycles)

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty much the same. Go to the world settings. And then under surface you can change the strength. Of course you
also can change the color of the environment there:

[image]

Comment: ... and set the *Color* of the *Surface* to *Sky Texture* (Cycles).

Comment: "Go to the world settings"... where are the world settings?? (dumd question maybe... but there's so many menus and buttons, I really can't seem to find it).

Comment: It is on the right side. The red planet you can see in the picture above. (Left to the word "volume")